# The application is in break mode -- cannot properly debug

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf application that I am creating and whenever I try to debug my code and reach an exception I am given the message "The application is in break mode". I am able to see the exception thrown but I am not given the line that the error was thrown.

I did look through some threads and the solution most people gave was to go to Tools > Options > Debugging > General > then to uncheck Enable Just My Code. I did this and I get a similar error but instead the error message is "AsyncMethodBuilder.cs not found". I then looked for a solution to that error and was told to check Enable Just My Code.

Is there a solution to "The application is in break mode" that does not consist of unchecking Enable Just My Code?

Comment: So you are using some third-party code that throws an exception? If you can't fix their code, there is not much else to do than either getting rid of the code or ignore the exception (if it doesn't crash your app of course). If it runs fine without the debugger, try to delete any .pdb files in the output folder and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to rebuild the entire project and that seemed to fix my issue.